# Removing rows after a certain string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to delete all rows after the row containing the string "End of the 4th Quarter". Currently, this is row 474 but it will change depending on the game.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re

url = "http://www.espn.com/nba/playbyplay?gameId=400900395"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")

data_rows = soup.findAll("tr")[4:]

play_data = []
for i in range(len(data_rows)):
    play_row = []

    for td in data_rows[i].findAll('td'):
        play_row.append(td.getText())

    play_data.append(play_row)

df = pd.DataFrame(play_data)

df.to_html("pbp_data")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how I would tackle it:

```
ur_row = your_df.ix[your_df['Column_Name_Here']=='End of the 4th Quarter'].index.tolist()
```

`ur_row` is getting the index number of the row that meets the condition. Then we use slicing to get everythin up to that row. (The `+1` is to capture the row including "End of 4th Quarter")

```
df.iloc[:ur_row[0]+1]
```

Hope this is simple to follow. I will gladly explain more if need be!

Answer (score 4):

If you are sure there is always such a string somewhere in your data frame, you can use `idxmax()` to find out the corresponding index and then take all the rows before the index with `loc`:

```
df.loc[:(df == 'End of the 4th Quarter').any(1).idxmax()]
```

Here is a few lines at the end:

```
df.loc[:(df == 'End of the 4th Quarter').any(1).idxmax()].tail()
```

[image]

Comment: If you know which column to look the string for, you can ditch `any`: `df.loc[:(df['myColumn'] == 'End of the 4th Quarter').idxmax()]`. And if you want to remove the row with the first occurance of the string, do `df.loc[:(df['myColumn'] == 'End of the 4th Quarter').idxmax()-1]`. Added this since it took me some time to figure out the command line :)

Answer (score 1):

Identify the index of the row with:

```
row = df[df['Column Name'] == 'End of the 4th quarter'].index.tolist()[0]
```

And then keep only the rows up to that row with:

```
df = df.iloc[:row-1]
```